# $target.blurOverlay is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I want to cover the main page of my ASP.NET MVC website with a welcome text. A great sample of this scenario is already implemented [here](https://www.canva.com/). Of course, I want to implement something like this sample by using a jQuery plugin called `blur-overlay` which could be downloaded from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blur-overlay).

I want when the user clicks anywhere out of the welcome text, then the cover fades out forever.

I'm using `BundleConfig` to render all my JavaScript files as bellow:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/blur-overlay.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/CustomNavbar.js"));
```

I'm also using `BundleConfig` to render my CSS files.

Here are the summarized of my `_Layout.cshtml` page:

```
<body>
    <div class="enterance">
        <p>
            Welcome text goes here.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        @* Here are lots of HTML tags which I would like to be covered by the welcome text when someone comes into the site *@
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                // Browsers that don't (fully) support filters
                var browserIsEdge = /Edge\/\d+/.test(navigator.userAgent);
                var browserIsIE = /Trident\/\d+/.test(navigator.userAgent);
                var opacity = (browserIsEdge || browserIsIE) ? '0.75' : '0.5';

                // Grab the element you want to "wrap" with blur
                var $target = $('#page');

                // Grab the content you want to display in the overlay
                var $overlay = $('.enterance').detach().show();

                // Initialize the overlay
                $target.blurOverlay({
                    // Overlay content
                    content: $overlay,
                    // Background color of the overlay (use rgba for opacity)
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + opacity + ')',
                    // Blur amount (default 12px)
                    blurAmount: '10px',
                    // Duration of CSS transitions
                    transitionDuration: '500ms',
                    // Type of CSS transitions
                    transitionType: 'cubic-bezier(.22, .57, .27, .92)',
                    // Elements to "mask" (adds an extra overlay to improve visual contrast)
                    masks: [{
                        selector: '.mask-me', // Required
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
                        opacity: 1,
                        width: '400px',
                        height: '300px'
                    }],
                    // Override the z-index used for the overlay and masks
                    zIndex: 3333,
                    // Disable the blur filter (for incompatible/buggy browsers or whatever reason)
                    noFilter: browserIsEdge || browserIsIE
                });

                // Show the overlay
                $target.blurOverlay('show').then(function () {
                    console.log('overlay is showing');
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

My problem is that when the JavaScript code reaches the `$target.blurOverlay({` then the following error occurs:

> $target.blurOverlay is not a function

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You should probably import `blur-overlay.js` **after** you import `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery-ui-{version}.js` in your BundleConfig since they are dependencies of this plugin. Framework libraries at top or in separate bundles and plugin and custom scripts below. Order matters

Comment: @zgood, I changed the order but the problem is still there.

Comment: Are you getting any other js errors? Are the versions of your jquery libraries correct for this plugin?

Comment: @zgood, I don't have any other js errors. The version of jQuery and jQuery-UI of my site is correct, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `jQuery.noConflict();`. I think the problem was that I was using `Bootstrap` beside the `jQuery`, so I had to use `jQuery.noConflict();` to remove the conflict.